# list of views referencing a table

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to know if a particular table is being referenced by any Views or not.I used the below code which gives only SP's and function names:

```
select * from sys.objects p inner join sys.sql_modules m
on p.object_id = m.object_id 
where m.definition like '%abc%'
```

Please help!!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
select * 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS 
where VIEW_DEFINITION like '%abc%'
```

Comment: Beware that there is limited number of characters returned for each object (anything past the limit is truncated), so you can't absolutely depend on INFORMATION_SCHEMA in all circumstances.

Answer (score 14):

First, your query gives views in the result set (I tried it on AdentureWorks2012 -> Production.Product table):

[image]

If you're using SQL Server 2008 or above, you can use the [sys.sql_expression_dependencies](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677315.aspx) catalog view. For example:

```
SELECT 
referencing_object_name = o.name, 
referencing_object_type_desc = o.type_desc, 
referenced_object_name = referenced_entity_name, 
referenced_object_type_desc = o1.type_desc 
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies sed 
INNER JOIN sys.objects o 
ON sed.referencing_id = o.[object_id] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.objects o1 
ON sed.referenced_id = o1.[object_id] 
WHERE referenced_entity_name = 'YourTable'
```

It will give you nice look on each **by-name** dependency on a user-defined entity

[image]

For column level dependencies you can use the [sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677185.aspx) function

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

If you need to find database objects (e.g. tables, columns, triggers) by name - have a look at the **FREE** Red-Gate tool called [SQL Search](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/) which does this - it searches your entire database for any kind of string(s).

[image]

[image]

It's a great must-have tool for any DBA or database developer - did I already mention it's absolutely **FREE** to use for any kind of use??

If that doesn't fit your bill - you could also check out the [`sysdepends`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190325.aspx) catalog view in SQL Server - it lists what objects depend on what (see details in the MSDN docs).

To find out what objects depend on a given table, you could use something like:

```
SELECT 
 id,
 OBJECT_NAME(ID)
FROM sys.sysdepends
WHERE depid = OBJECT_ID('YourTable')
```

That should give you a list of all objects depending on that table (or view or whatever you're checking)